# How to get the child DOM element reference from Parent using angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-components

I need to get the child component DOM reference from parent component using angular 4, but i can't access child component DOM, please guide me how to achieve this.

parent.component.html

```
<child-component></child-component>
```

parent.component.ts

```js
import { Component, Input, ViewChild, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'parent-component',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html'
})
export class ParentComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('tableBody') tableBody: ElementRef;
  constructor(){
    console.log(this.tableBody);//undefined
  }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
       console.log(this.tableBody);//undefined
   }
}
```

child.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'child-component',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html'
})
export class ChildComponent { 
}
```

child.component.html

```
<div>
        <table border="1">
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <tbody #tableBody>
        <tr>
         <td>ABCD</td>
          <td>12</td>
        </tr>        
      </tbody>
        </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To expand on Sachila Ranawaka answer:

First you need `<child-component #childComp></child-component>`

In your parent component, instead of `ElementRef` it should be `ChildComponent`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'parent-component',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html'
})
export class ParentComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('childComp') childComp: ChildComponent;
  constructor(){
  }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.childComp.tableBody);
  }
}
```

For your child component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child-component',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html'
})
export class ChildComponent { 
  @ViewChild('tableBody') tableBody: ElementRef;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Adding to Sachila's and penleychan's good answers, you can reference a component with `@ViewChild` just by its component's name:

parent.component.html

```
<!-- You don't need to template reference variable on component -->   
<child-component></child-component>
```

Then in parent.component.ts

```
import { ChildComponent } from './child-component-path';

@Component({
  selector: 'parent-component',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html'
})
export class ParentComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild(ChildComponent) childComp: ChildComponent;
  constructor(){
  }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.childComp.tableBody);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Need to reference the `tableBody` from the parent component. So add it to he `child-component` and remove it from `tbody`

```
<child-component #tableBody></child-component>
```

Comment: this will give access to child component not table body which is part of child component

Comment: @thilagabala This answer is not wrong just incomplete.

Comment: @12seconds, correct me if i'm wrong, if i could do the above code, i can get child component methods and binding values instead of DOM.

Comment: @thilagabala check my answer, think it answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

just to add here , if you also need to change the DOM element attributes then once you have got access of child component Dom as demonstrated in   @penleychan answer.
after that just set the color.
let parentdiv= this.childComp.tableBody.nativeElement;
parentdiv.style.backgroundColor='red';